# get coordinates of an element in QWebView of QtWebKit, PyQt4 and autoscroll to its position

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit, qwebview

Here is a a simple code which opens a site (say, yahoo.com) in `QWebView`. After finishing loading the site it scrolls to a certain position (say, `QPoint(100, 300)`). We need to wait for the site to finish loading, otherwise it wouldn't scroll automatically, hence `loadFinished` signal.

But the question is: how can i find coordinates of an element (say 'All Stories' at yahoo.com) and automatically scroll to its position like I manually did it in the picture below? There are functions like `findFirstElement`, `findAllElements` in `QWebFrame` but I don't know how to find x, y coordinates using them?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

def loadFinished():
    web.page().mainFrame().setScrollPosition(QPoint(100, 300))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://yahoo.com"))
web.connect(web, SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), loadFinished)
web.setGeometry(700, 500, 300, 500)
web.setWindowTitle('yahoo')
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`QWebElement.geometry()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html#geometry):

```
def loadFinished():
    elements = web.page().mainFrame().findAllElements(css_selector)
    for index in range(elements.count()):
        print(elements.at(index).geometry())
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested, here is my final code (based on ekhumoro advice to use `QWebElement.geometry()`):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

def loadFinished():
    html = web.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
    # I couldn't find a way to find html element by text 'All Stories',
    # so copied this weird unique attribute from yahoo page source code
    el = html.findFirst('a[data-ylk="sec:strm;cpos:1;elm:itm;elmt:fltr;pos:0;ft:1;itc:1;t1:a3;t2:strm;t3:lst"]')
    qp = el.geometry().topLeft()  # returns QPoint object
    # we can either use QPoint position as is:
    # web.page().mainFrame().setScrollPosition(qp)
    # or calibrate x, y coordinates a little:
    web.page().mainFrame().setScrollPosition(QPoint(qp.x() - 15, qp.y()))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://yahoo.com"))
web.loadFinished.connect(loadFinished)
web.setGeometry(700, 500, 300, 500)
web.setWindowTitle('yahoo')
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]